# Cannot find colour scheme

Tags: vim, colors

I am trying to install a colour scheme called "github", which I got from the vim site and I have followed exactly how to install it by adding `github.vim` to my `~/.vim/colors` folder. However, I get the error message "Cannot find colour scheme `github.vim`" after executing:

```
:colorscheme github.vim
```

I can't seem to find the issue after searching countless posts for a solution, so if anybody could help that'd be great. :)

Answer (score 8):

Try this command instead:

```
:colorscheme github
```

You should not be using the `.vim` extension for the `colorscheme` command.

To see the full range of colors in the colorscheme you would need to use `gvim` since the terminal version of `vim` would be limited in the number of colors it can display.

Comment: It changes colours around,but not what it should change to. The theme should be a white colour, but it remains black with a few parts of the text changing to white.

It really is frustrating. Anything else you can suggest? :)

Comment: @Shazer2 - vim would honor the settings in the colorscheme file. Do you have a link to it or its source that we could try ?

Comment: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2855 - this is the github theme I am trying to install.

Comment: Just tried the github colorscheme with both vim and gvim and I see the expected results as shown on the vim.org page.

Comment: I can guarantee it isn't working for me. Here are some screenshots, before command execution ([link](http://i.imgur.com/ldgHkfX.png)), after execution ([link](http://i.imgur.com/Wg1ifR6.png)).

Comment: @Shazer2 - the colorscheme is meant to be used primarily with `gvim` to see the full range of colors as shown in the screenshot. Since `vim` just runs in the terminal it would be able to display only limited number of colors. Can you try the same command with `gvim` to see if it works for you ?

Comment: That was the problem, it runs fine in gvim. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

The theme you're using is a gui only theme. You can use Gvim or try another theme. Take a look at summerfruit256: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2577.